# Reading in bytes produced by PHP script in Java to create a bitmap

Tags: java, php, database, android, bitmap

I'm having trouble getting the compressed jpeg image (stored as a blob in my database).

here is the snippet of code I use to output the image that I have in my database:

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $size = $row['image_size'];
    $image = $row['image'];
    if($image == null){
        echo "no image!";
    } else {
       header('Content-Type: content/data');
       header("Content-length: $size");
       echo $image;
    }
}
```

here is the code that I use to read in from the server:

```
        URL sizeUrl = new URL(MYURL);
        URLConnection sizeConn = sizeUrl.openConnection();

        // Get The Response
        BufferedReader sizeRd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sizeConn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while(line.equals("")){
            line = sizeRd.readLine();
        }
        int image_size = Integer.parseInt(line);

        if(image_size == 0){
            return null;
        }

        URL imageUrl = new URL(MYIMAGEURL);
        URLConnection imageConn = imageUrl.openConnection();

        // Get The Response
        InputStream imageRd = imageConn.getInputStream();


        byte[] bytedata = new byte[image_size];
        int read = imageRd.read(bytedata, 0, image_size);

        Log.e("IMAGEDOWNLOADER", "read "+ read + " amount of bytes");
        Log.e("IMAGEDOWNLOADER", "byte data has length " + bytedata.length);

        Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytedata, 0, image_size);
        if(theImage == null){
            Log.e("IMAGEDOWNLOADER", "the bitmap is null");
        }
        return theImage;
```

My logging shows that everything has the right length, yet theImage is always null.
I'm thinking it has to do with my content type. Or maybe the way I'm uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function. It works for me:

```
Bitmap loadPhotoBitmap(URL url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/photo-tmp.jpg");
        BufferedOutputStream bfs = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);                    
        out.flush();
        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();

        bfs.write(data, 0, data.length);
        bfs.flush();

        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        android.util.Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not load file: " + this, e);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out)
        closeStream(bfs);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: what is the copy method that you're using?